# EmberJS: How to Redirect from Route, Keeping Query Params

Tags: redirect, ember.js, ember-data

I want to redirect from a route, `/new`, and keep the query params for the `new` route:

As far as I know, the only place to access `queryParams` is within the `model` hook of a route.

But I want to redirect in the [`beforeModel` hook](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel):

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    /**
     * @@override
     * Implicitly create a new applicant, redirecting to the generated ID at /applications/#{id}
     * @param transition
     */
    beforeModel: function(transition) {
        var emptyApplicant = this.store.createRecord("applicant",
                {isPrimary: true}
            ),
            emptyApplication = this.store.createRecord("application");
        emptyApplication.set("applicant", emptyApplicant);
        emptyApplicant.save().then((savedApplicant) => {
            emptyApplication.save().then((savedApplication) => {
                this.transitionTo("applications", savedApplication);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

While the above code works, the transition will complete **without preserving** the query params.  For example, navigating to `applicants/new?agent=35` will not preserve `agent=35` in the query param, and will simply redirect to `applicants/new` instead.

How can I access the `queryParams` object from the `beforeModel` hook in my Ember app?

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to pass [query parameters](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo) to the `transitionTo`, something along the line of:

```
this.transitionTo("applications", savedApplication, {
  queryParams: transition.queryParams
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In more modern versions of Ember, the [transition object has a to property](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.21/classes/Transition/properties/to?anchor=to) which contains the query params. Transition no longer has a `queryParams` property

A redirect to the `index` route in a `beforeModel` for example, might look like this:

```
beforeModel(transition){
  super.beforeModel(...arguments);
  transition.abort();
  this.transitionTo('index', {
    queryParams: transition.to.queryParams
  });
}
```